# Devbridge jQuery Autocomplete : local search after a first query returned results

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

Is it possible (using callbacks I guess) to cache a first result (after 3 characters have been entered for example) and switch to local if the user adds more characters?
Right now if we add characters to the same root search a new ajax call is triggered.
This would save a lot of time and save the server.
I could use the onSearchComplete in order to setup variables after a first search and then onSearchStart for the next search where I would check the variables (search term should have the same root and previous suggestions should not be empty) and then I switch from ajax source to local source.
My issue is that I don't think I can change the source to local from within the onSearchStart callback.

Please note I am not a js expert...ie my question.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, for lookup you can pass function where you can query server yourself. So you can cache results yourself and just return anything you want:

```
lookup: function (query, done) {
    // Do ajax request here
    // When completed pass results to "done" callback:
    // done(results);
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks. I accept the answer however this would make sense for the library to filter on cache instead of querying...